# Inserting row for every value of array(checkbox value) Code igniter

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have this view that outputs a check box for every row in my database, and it works perfectly fine.

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2" >CheckBox:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
               <div class="form-group">
                 <?php foreach($content1 as $cb){ ?>
                    <div class="checkbox">
                      <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="h[]" value = "<?php echo $cb->USERCODE?>">
                        <?php echo $cb->DEPARTMENT.' '.$cb->USERTYPE?>
                      </label>
                     </div>
                <?php } ?>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I print_r it already have its value in an array for example:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 [2] => 6 [3] => 7 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 1 )
```

Now what I want to achieve is for every value that is checked, it will enter in the database. For example, I only chose the value under for the group POSTVALUE, which I input in an input type="text".

```
 Array ( 
[0] => 2 
[1] => 3 
[2] => 4  )
```

My model will query

```
insert into table column , column1 values '2' , 'POSTVALUE';
insert into table column , column1 values '3' , 'POSTVALUE';
insert into table column , column1 values '4' , 'POSTVALUE';
```

Answer (score 2):

After submit value pass that value from controller to model function. 
In controller use this function.

```
public function form_action()
{

    $h= $this->input->post('h');
    $data=array(
    'postvalue' => $this->input->post('postvalue'),
    'h' => $h
    );
  $this->model_name->insert_value($data);
}
```

Here is your sample model function. This will help you.

```
public function insert_value($data)
{        
    $n =0;
    foreach($data['h'] as $rows) {
        $data[$n] = array(
        'column' => $rows,
        'column1' => $data['postvalue'],
        );
        $query = $this->db->insert('table_name',$data[$n]);
        $n++;
    }


    if($query)
    {

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: should it be `$n = 1` or `$n = 0` because arrays start with 0 am i right?

Answer (score 2):

Your **Model** should look like this

you can try with a simple insert

```
function insert_checkbox($array){
    foreach ($array as $row){
      $data = ['column'=>$row];
      $this->db->insert('table', $data); 
    }
}
```

you can also try with `insert_batch()`

```
function insert_checkbox($array){
    $data = [];
    foreach ($array as $row){
      $data[] = ['column'=>$row];
    }
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $data); 
 }
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data)

Comment: if i use this what would my controller look like? just the normal way?

Comment: `$this->My_Model->function($array);` ??

Comment: Yes. just the normal way you call a function.
in your controller: `$this->my_model->insert_checkbox($array); `

Comment: what if i want to insert another value to the database per item in the array

Comment: can i do `$data[] =  ['column' => $this->input->post('value'), 'column'=>$row];`

Comment: show us the array you are actually sending to the model... i can not predict what you have...

Comment: and by the way i got Message: Undefined variable: array error on the codes that you gave

Comment: `$array` is supposed to be the name of the array you printed on the question... you gave no name for that array, so I invented a simple name for this...

Comment: on `<input type="checkbox" name="h[]"`  is the ` name="h[]"`?? am i correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106718/discussion-between-kev-m-and-david-bm).